# Пропускает ввод данных

Tags: c++

Помогите исправить ошибку в коде:

```
    #pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int mass_width, mass_height; // длина строки, и количество
    int string_length;
    // SetConsoleCP(1252); // Для корректного отображения русс.яз.
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // Для корректного отображения русс.яз.
    string_length = 0;
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "Количество строк в массиве: ";
    cin >> mass_height;
    cout << "Максимальная длина строки: ";
    cin >> mass_width;
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    char **ptrarray = new char* [mass_height]; // столбцы в массиве
    for (int count = 0; count < mass_height; count++)
        ptrarray[count] = new char[mass_width]; // строки
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int count = 0; count <= mass_height; count++) {
        printf("Введите строку № %d: ", count);
        fgets(ptrarray[count], mass_width, stdin);
        int length = strlen(ptrarray[count]);
        if (length > 0 && ptrarray[count][length - 1] == '\n')
            ptrarray[count][length - 1] = '\0';
        if (length > string_length) {
            string_length = length;
        }
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "Максимальная длинна строки = " << string_length - 1;
    // -1 из-за терминирующего нуля
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Результат программы:

> Количество строк в массиве: 10
> Максимальная длина строки: 99
> Введите строку № 0: Введите строку № 1:

Как видите, не получается ввести данные в строку №0. Где я ошибся?

Comment: а для чего функция fgets() вызывается? это же вроде функция для считывания с файла, а вы не работаете с файлом ((

Comment: @Roman Goriachevskiy, обратите внимание на третий параметр функции `fgets`. В качестве него передаётся `stdin`, который отражает ввод с консоли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя количество строк - `mass_height`; ты создаёшь `mass_height` строк, но пытаешься прочитать `mass_height` строк, так как у тебя цикл `for (int count = 0; count <= mass_height; count++)` вместо `for (int count = 0; count < mass_height; count++)`. 
Ещё тебе нужно после `cin >> mass_width`; добавить `cin.get()`; 
Вместо `fgets(ptrarray[count], mass_width, stdin)`; использовать `cin.getline(ptrarray[count], mass_width)`; и тогда можно избавиться от первого if'а и выводя длину самой длинной строки не нужно будет отнимать единичку.у меня почему-то не работает setConsoleOutputCP.  вот код.

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    int mass_width, mass_height; // длина строки, и количество
    int string_length;
    //SetConsoleCP(1252); // Для корректного отображения русс.яз.
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); // Для корректного отображения русс.яз.
    string_length = 0;
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "kolichestvo strok v massive: ";
    cin >> mass_height;
    cout << "maksimalnaya dlina stroki: ";
    cin >> mass_width;
    cin.get();
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    char **ptrarray = new char* [mass_height]; // столбцы в массиве
    for (int count = 0; count < mass_height; count++)
        ptrarray[count] = new char[mass_width]; // строки
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for (int count = 0; count < mass_height; count++) {
        cout << "Vvedite strolu nomver " << count << ": ";
        cin.getline(ptrarray[count], mass_width);
        int length = strlen(ptrarray[count]);
        if (length > string_length) {
            string_length = length;
        }
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cout << "maksimalnaya dlina stroli = " << string_length;
    // -1 из-за терминирующего нуля
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ПКМ по окну консоли--свойства и выбери другой щрифт

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что после прочтения второго числа (`mass_width`) во входном потоке остаётся символ перевода строки (`'\n'`), который и читается в строку №0. Перед чтением массива `char`'ов следует очистить `stdin` функцией `fflush(stdin)`.

P.S. Ваш учитель редкостный чудак, мешать чтение с помощью потоков (C++ style) и stdin (C style) - редкостное убожество. Заставлять при этом пользоваться массивами `char`'ов вместо строк - вообще садизм.

Comment: @ms301, прямо скажу, fflush(stdin) сработает для командной строки, но при переадресации stdin из файла будет работать некорректно (т.к. отбросит **все** буферизованные данные).

Правильный подход при переходе от форматного (поэлементного) чтения потока к чтению по строкам - это посимвольное чтение до '\n'.

Например

     #define skipnl(f) ({ int c; while((c = fgetc(f)) != '\n') if (c == EOF) break; c; })
     ...
     scanf ("%d", &a);  // иди cin >> a;
     ...
     skipnl(stdin);
     fgets (str, sizeof(str), stdin);

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, проблема вот в чём. Вы не должны вводить числа через `cin`. А ещё, вы не проверяете, как отработал `cin <<` — успешно или нет.

Смотрите, что у вас во входном потоке: 10, `\n`, 99, `\n` и т д.

Строка `cin >> mass_height;` считывает из потока 10. Следующий ввод `cin >> mass_width;` натыкается на `\n` и завершается с ошибкой. В состоянии ошибки остальной ввод тоже не работает.

Вам надо вводить данные через [`getline`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) в строку (ради всего святого, не пользуйтесь `char[]` в качестве строки, иначе проблемы будете разгребать до конца года), и вытаскивать из неё число (например, при помощи [`stringstream`](/questions/202681/)).

---

Если вам необходимо пользоваться `char[]` для строк, к вашим услугам соответственно [`cin.getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

```
// вспомогательная функция
bool stoa(char* s, int& out)
{
    istringstream iss(s);
    return !!(iss >> out);
}

char inputBuffer[256];
cin.getline(inputBuffer, 256);

if (!stoa(inputBuffer, mass_height))
{
    cout << "wtf?" << endl;
    return 1;
}
// тут у mass_height введённое значение
// ну и так далее
```

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием пользовался строками, но учитель задал такую задачу: Создать 2-х мерный символьный массив, что бы пользователь ввел строки, и программа бы нашла самую длинную строку. Если я не правильно что то понял-с удовольствием выслушаю комментарии))) (с++ недавно начали учить, многого еще не знаю)
P.S. а webdelphi.ru это же Ваш сайт?

Comment: Эх! Скажите учителю, что он не знает и не понимает C++/ Ну или хоть подумайте так :-)

---
Не, у меня вообще нету сайта.

Comment: Он может и понимает, но обучает нас в режиме "Сделай лабораторную с помощью интернета". Практика конечно хорошо, но теории не хватает((

Comment: Обновил ответ (код не тестировал, но должен сработать).